# SQL Server : printing all the rows from left table while using aggregate operator COUNT()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, left-join, aggregate-functions

I am trying to write a query that returns a count of `TotalPlayers` in each team who scored less than 10 runs as `[LowScoringPlayers]`, if all the players in a team scored more than 10 runs, I still need to print the `TeamName` and 0 as the `[LowScoringPlayers]` for that team.

My below query gives me the count correctly but if there are no players in a team who scored less than 10 runs then it skips printing that `TeamName`.

```
SELECT DISTCINT
    (TM.[TeamId]), TM.[TeamName], 
    COUNT(DISTINCT S.[PlayerId]) AS [LowScoringPlayers]
FROM 
    dbo.[Teams] TM
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.[Player] PL ON PL.[PlayerId] = TM.[TeamId]
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.[ScoreAudit] S ON S.[PlayerId] = PL.[PlayerId] AND S.[Runs] <= 10
GROUP BY 
    TM.[TeamId], TM.[TeamName]
```

If I remove the condition `S.[Runs] <=10` the query prints all the team names.. 1 way I could think of is using a case statement before `S.[Runs] <=10`, but the data is huge so there might be performance issues.

Any other better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` in your query. So, solution can be:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TM.TeamId, TM.TeamName, COUNT(DISTINCT S.PlayerId) AS LowScoringPlayers
FROM dbo.Teams TM
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Player PL
        ON PL.PlayerId = TM.TeamId
     LEFT JOIN dbo.ScoreAudit S
        ON S.PlayerId = PL.PlayerId AND S.Runs <=10
    GROUP BY TM.TeamId, TM.TeamName
```